# css masonry - incorrect item wrapping

Tags: html, css, grid, masonry, css-grid

I'm trying to implement a "masonry" grid ... well, tricks using css `column-count` to achieve such.

Here's a tutorial I am following:
http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/

I'm finding the last item in the first column to "wrap".
It gets truncated and some appears at the bottom of the column, while the rest appears at the top of the second panel.

[image]

How can I prevent this?

Here's some code:

```
.masonry {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 0;
}

<div className="masonry">
  <div style={{display: 'inline-block', float: 'left', width: '100%', height: '285px', backgroundColor: 'red', margin: '0 0 1em'}}></div>
  <div style={{display: 'inline-block', float: 'left', width: '100%', height: '196px', backgroundColor: 'green', margin: '0 0 1em'}}></div>
  <div style={{display: 'inline-block', float: 'left', width: '100%', height: '183px', backgroundColor: 'blue', margin: '0 0 1em'}}></div>
  <div style={{display: 'inline-block', float: 'left', width: '100%', height: '234px', backgroundColor: 'orange', margin: '0 0 1em'}}></div>
  <div style={{display: 'inline-block', float: 'left', width: '100%', height: '123px', backgroundColor: 'yellow', margin: '0 0 1em'}}></div>
</div>
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44377343/3597276

Comment: It seems that `float: left` was the culprit!

Comment: I've also found that having margins on the items causes calculation issues.